# Оптимизация кода. Задача "Защищенность пешек на шахматной доске"

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Доброго времени суток, друзья.

Прошу дать критику моему "коду", и по-возможности дать советы по оптимизации того, что я попытался "накодить". Спасибо.

Задача стоит следующая.
Шахматная доска, на ней расположены только пешки одной стороны (белые), координаты пешек даны. Проверить, расположены ли на доске пешки, так, чтобы быть под защитой. (Т.е. стоит ли одна пешка, на диагонали другой, тем самым "защищая её")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моё решение данной задачи:

```
def safe_pawns(pawns):
    pawn_indexes = list() #Координаты, данные в задаче, планируем хранить в списке
    for i in pawns:       #Пробегаю по списку, перевожу координаты шахмат в цифровые значения
        rows = int(i[1])-1
        colums = (ord(i[0])-97)
        pawn_indexes.append((colums, rows))

    count = 0             #Создаю счетчик, где будет хранится кол-во найденных "диагоналей"
    for j in pawn_indexes:
        if pawn_indexes.count((j[0] - 1, j[1] - 1)) != 0:
            count = count + (pawn_indexes.count((j[0] - 1, j[1] - 1)))
        else:
            count = count + (pawn_indexes.count((j[0] + 1, j[1] - 1)))
    return count
```

Проверка выполняется через следующий тест:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert safe_pawns({"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"}) == 6
    assert safe_pawns({"b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4", "e5"}) == 1
```

Прошу вас, дать замечания по коду, и по-возможности, сделать его "красивее".

Спасибо.

Comment: Если код рабочий и вас интересуют любые отклики по нему, то добавьте метку [tag:инспекция-кода]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для читаемости, можно вместо индексов `i[0]`, `i[1]` использовать именованные атрибуты `pawn.column`, `pawn.row`.

Чтобы узнать защищена ли пешка, достаточно проверить есть ли на доске пешка слева/внизу или справа/внизу. Так как `a..h`, `1..8` символы идут подряд в Unicode, то достаточно вычесть/добавить единицу к их номерам (Unicode code point), чтобы получить позиции слева/справа:

```
def is_safe(pawn, board):
    return (Pawn(pawn.column-1, pawn.row-1) in board
         or Pawn(pawn.column+1, pawn.row-1) in board)
```

Формула универсальная и работает и для пешек на краю доски.

Посчитать количество защищённых пешек, имея их набор такой как `{"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"}` можно за два шага:

1. Добавить пешки на игровую доску в виде объектов с численными `.column`, `.row` свойствами (чтобы приведённая реализация `is_safe()` работала), используя к примеру [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
2. Посчитать количество пешек, для которых `is_safe()` возвращает истину:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Pawn = namedtuple('Pawn', "column row")

def count_safe(pawns):
    board = {Pawn(ord(column), ord(row)) for column, row in pawns}  # добавляем
    return sum(1 for pawn in board if is_safe(pawn, board))         # считаем
```

Пример:

```py
>>> count_safe({"b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4", "e5"})
1
>>> count_safe({"b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"})
6
```

---

Доску ещё можно собрать, используя [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
columns, rows = zip(*pawns)
board = set(map(Pawn, map(ord, columns), map(int, rows)))
```

но это менее читаемо чем:

```py
board = {Pawn(ord(column), int(row)) for column, row in pawns}
```

---

С точки зрения производительности `pawn in board` быстрее если `isinstance(board, set)` по сравнению `isinstance(board, list)` даже для таких маленьких `len(board) == 8`. Если profiler не говорит, что `pawn in board` является узким местом в вашем коде, то разницу set/list можно игнорировать в данном случае.

Comment: Супер разъяснения, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
def diagonal(x: 'd', y: '2') -> str:
    '''координаты диагоналей'''
    x, y = ord(x), chr(ord(y) - 1)  # 100, '1'
    yield chr(x - 1) + y  # 'c1'
    yield chr(x + 1) + y  # 'e1'

def check(coordinates: [str, ]) -> (str, str):
    '''защищенность координат'''
    for coord in coordinates:
        yield coord,  'safe' if any(d in coordinates for d in diagonal(*coord)) else 'unsafe'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = list(check(['b5', 'b1', 'a2', 'd2', 'e3', 'c3', 'f4', 'd4', 'b4', 'g5', 'h4', 'g2', 'h1']))
    print(result)  # [('b5', 'unsafe'), ('b1', 'unsafe'), ('a2', 'safe'), ('d2', 'unsafe'), ('e3', 'safe'), ('c3', 'safe'), ('f4', 'safe'), ('d4', 'safe'), ('b4', 'safe'), ('g5', 'safe'), ('h4', 'unsafe'), ('g2', 'safe'), ('h1', 'unsafe')]
```

доска с result:

```
    def show_result():
        t = '{a:^6}{b:^6}{c:^6}{d:^6}{e:^6}{f:^6}{g:^6}{h:^6}'
        res = [{}.fromkeys('abcdefgh', '-') for _ in range(8)]
        for (x, y), r in result:
            res[int(y)-1][x] = r

        print('_' * 55)
        for e, dt in reversed(list(enumerate(res, start=1))):
            print(' %s |' % e, t.format(**dt), '|')
        print('_'*55)
       print('\t', t.format(**{k: k for k in 'abcdefgh'}))

    show_result()
```

out:

```
_______________________________________________________
 8 |   -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -    |
 7 |   -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -    |
 6 |   -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -    |
 5 |   -   unsafe  -     -     -     -    safe   -    |
 4 |   -    safe   -    safe   -    safe   -   unsafe |
 3 |   -     -    safe   -    safe   -     -     -    |
 2 |  safe   -     -   unsafe  -     -    safe   -    |
 1 |   -   unsafe  -     -     -     -     -   unsafe |
_______________________________________________________
       a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h
```